# how to update (append to it) an href based on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can append to an href link a value based on a dropdown selection?

Example :

```
<option value="100" selected="selected">MyList</option>
```

And a hyperlink like:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/insert/place_where_insert_the_selected_value"></a>
```

So the link will be :

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/insert/100"></a>
```

Thanks for your support

I tried

```
$('#IdMenuToEdit').change(function() {

    var id = $( "#IdMenuToEdit option:selected" ).val();
    var href = $('a.with-tip[name="DeleteMenu"]').attr("href");

    $('a.with-tip[name="DeleteMenu"]').attr('href',href+"/"+id);



});
```

it works but not very elegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

change_link();

```
$("select").change(function(){
    change_link();
});
function change_link(){
    var val = $("select option:selected").val();
    $("a").each(function(){
        var nhref = "";
        var href = $(this).attr("href").split("/");
        for(var i=0;i<href.length-1;i++){
            nhref += href[i]+"/";
        }
        nhref += val;
        $(this).attr("href",nhref);
    });
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/72Pvt/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
var valselected = $('select option:selected').val();
$('a').attr('href','www.mysite.com/insert/'+valselected);
```

Its something like that, i could give more complete answer if you give more complete code.
To be more precise this code need some "id" or "name" from the components like combobox and

Answer (score 0):

This would be a more efficient approach:

let your html be like this:

```
<select id="mycombo">
<option value="100" selected="selected">MyList</option>
... 
</select> 
 <a id="mylink" href="www.mysite.com/insert/"></a>
```

now,  you capture combo's change event, then you change link href depending on the selected value. The first time,   you save the base_href, to avoid to compute it each time.

```
var base_href="";
$('#mycombo').on('change', function() {
   var value=$(this).val();
    if (base_href=="")
        base_href = $("#mylink").attr("href");
   $("#mylink").attr("href",base_href+value);
 });
```